# Android Webview loadUrl works but not loadDataWithBaseURL

Tags: android, webview

I have files downloaded into my app's storage at `file:///data/data/<myapp>/files/folder/`.  The files downloaded into the folder include a **HTML, css, js and image files**. When using webview's loadUrl, the following code works perfectly for me:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///data/data/<myapp>/files/folder/filename.html");
```

But now I need to download the HTML file because I need to encrypt it before storing it.  The problem is not encrypting the information (at the moment).  All I am trying to do is download the HTML content into a string and then use webview's loadDataWithBaseURL to load the webview.  When trying to do this, I am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError" and "Uncaught ReferenceError" from the web console.  I'm not sure as to where these errors are coming from.

I'm using the following code to download the HTML into a string:

```
URL url = new URL("myserver/filename.html");
InputStream input = null;
input = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    sb.append(line)
}

String myHTML = sb.toString();
```

Now when I go to load webview with loadDataWithBaseURL:

```
String baseURL = "file:///data/data/<myapp>/files/folder/";

WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);  

webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseURL, myHTML, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

But when I execute this code, I get `"Uncaught SyntaxError"` and `"Uncaught ReferenceError"`.  Now I am confused because if loadUrl works perfectly fine, why isn't my loadDataWithBaseURL acting in the same behavior?  Is it because I'm not converting the HTML into a string correctly? or is it the HTML code itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was html coding error.  The above method works perfectly fine if you are trying to download an HTML.